# How can I add/write files to a .img binary file (created with dd and has ext3 as fs)?

Tags: file, ext3, diskimage

I have a bit of a trouble trying to add/write files to a .img raw disk file created with dd and which has a ext3 filesystem.

I know I could use mount/fusermount but I would like to avoid this and use other methods.

Any ideas are welcomed!

Thank you!

Comment: There's no other methods than to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

I could've used genext2fs with tune2fs to enable journaling.